# How to create a table that lists all the names in one table and counts the number of times it appears in another one?

Tags: mysql

I have to create a table named vecesCarcel which whenever I insert a name, it automatically adds another cell with the number of times the name appears in another table. So far I've tried with triggers this, but without result:

```
USE lordfarquaad;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vecesCarcel(
   nombrePersonaje    VARCHAR(10),
   veces              INTEGER(5) UNSIGNED)
   ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE vecesCarcel
  ADD CONSTRAINT vecesCarcelFK1 FOREIGN KEY(nombrePersonaje)
    REFERENCES personajes(nombrePersonaje)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


USE lordfarquaad;   
DELIMITER $$  


CREATE PROCEDURE checkvecescarcel(IN nombre VARCHAR(10),OUT veces INT(5))
BEGIN 
SET veces=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historiales WHERE nombrePersonaje=nombre);
END
$$


CREATE TRIGGER vecesCarcel_Insert BEFORE INSERT ON vecesCarcel FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     CALL checkvecescarcel(NEW.nombrePersonaje,NEW.veces);
  END;
  $$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a trigger, you have to set the new.veces-value inside the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER vecesCarcel_Insert BEFORE INSERT ON vecesCarcel FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.veces=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historiales 
                   WHERE nombrePersonaje=NEW.nombrePersonaje);
```

You might want to create an `on update`-trigger, too (same code, so you can aswell put `select count(*)...` in a function and use `set new.veces = myfnct(new.nombrepersonaje)`).

But keep in mind your count will not update itself if you change anything in the table `historiales` (e.g. add another entry with the name in the list). So, depending on your setup, and if your `historiales`-table can change, or if you just might want to try a different approach, you can try a view:

```
create view vecesCarcelView as
select nombrePersonaje, 
       (select count(*) 
        from historiales 
        where vecesCarcel.nombrePersonaje=historiales.nombrePersonaje) as veces
from vecesCarcel;
```

(If you don't care so much about the order, you can do this with a `left join` and a `group by` too; and you could actually use the view with the whole `personajes`-table to display the count for all known names.)